# Differences between get_by_id() vs objects.get() vs objects.filter()

Tags: django

I'm just looking to see what the differences are between:

```
obj = ClassModel.get_by_id(object_id)

obj = ClassModel.objects.get(pk=object_id)

obj = ClassModel.objects.filter(pk=object_id)
```

The first one, I defined myself by extending `models.Model`, but I'm not sure if it's good convention creating an extra method to do what can be done with the second option.

Are the consequences of using the first option over the second option? Is it safe to use it or is it just going to add code debt to my code?

Comment: `get_by_id` gets an Object by ID (like you said, pretty self explanatory). `get` returns a database row, and `filter` returns a `queryset`

Comment: `get_by_id` doesn't exist, unless you define it. And why would you bother?